# Devstack installation fail at python update.py /opt/stack//cinder

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-cinder

i am new to openstack. while installing devstack on virtual box uisng ubuntu i am getting the following error. can any one help me to fix the problem. The error prompt is as follows.

- cd /opt/stack/requirements
- python update.py /opt/stack/cinder

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "update.py", line 505, in 
    main()

File "update.py", line 488, in main

```
options.hacking, stdout, options.verbose, non_std_reqs)
```

File "update.py", line 500, in _do_main

```
project, global_reqs, suffix, softupdate, hacking, non_std_reqs)
```

File "update.py", line 371, in _process_project

```
suffix, softupdate, hacking, project, global_reqs, non_std_reqs)
```

File "update.py", line 284, in _copy_requires
    non_std_reqs)

File "update.py", line 255, in _sync_requirements_file

```
raise Exception("nonstandard requirement present.")
```

Exception: nonstandard requirement present.
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]

- kill_spinner
- '[' '!' -z '' ']'
- [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
- echo 'Error on exit'

Error on exit
+ [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+ /home/faraz/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-06-21-174507.txt for details
+ exit 1

Comment: What errors do you see in /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-06-21-174507.txt?

Comment: mysql    14832 15178  0.6  2.9 728688 120844 ?       Sl   21:48:12 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

Comment: Well, not much information there. Is that all you see in the log?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the procedure you were following? A link maybe. Which version of DevStack are you installing? My pretty fresh copy of DevStack (about a month ago) doesn't seem to match yours.